# NSDateFormatter have extra dot in front of month for nb_NO (Norsk Bokmal) locale

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsdateformatter

I'm working in a *Xamarin.IOs* project. I'm trying to convert a *DateTime* object into the following format "**dd. MMM yyyy**" under "*nb_NO*" locale which should return something like, **Ex:** "**05. feb 2018**".

I'm using the following code snippets to achieve this, *(C#)*

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var format = "dd. MMM yyyy";
var formatter = new NSDateFormatter { DateFormat = format, Locale = new NSLocale("nb_NO"), TimeZone = NSTimeZone.SystemTimeZone };
var nsDate = DateTimeToNSDate(now);
var formattedDate = formatter.StringFor(nsDate);
```

But what I get for `formattedDate` is something like **Ex:** "**05. feb. 2018**". There is an *extra dot* (period) after the month as well.

What can I do to get rid of this unexpected extra dot after the month in "*nb_NO*" locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research, I tried the following string format, "**dd. LLL yyyy**".

You have to use **LLL** instead of **MMM** to render the month.

This just solved me the issue.

You can find all the possible formats [here](https://waracle.com/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)!